# Unable to move Computer account to new ou after moving it once

Tags: active-directory

I have allocated the following rights to a user group to the parent OU:
Allow Create/delete computer object
Allow Read
Allow Write all properties.

Now this allows them to move computer objects around like I expected. However when they go to move the computer object a second time they don't have rights to do so.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I implemented permissions like this on purpose once. We had a team whose sole job was to build servers, then turn them over to other teams to configure and manage them. I allowed them to create the AD computer object in the default container, and then move that computer object exactly once - hopefully into the OU of the proper team who was to own that server. If you don't have the rights to delete computers out of an OU then you cannot move it out of that OU.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your OU structure I would advise you to check these things:

1. The "Applies to" section of your allow ACEs. It should be "This folder, subfolders and files"
2. Check if the has "Protect from accidental deletion" checked in Object tab of the computer account. This checkbox adds explicit DENY ACEs in object's ACL which take precedence.

Also, IIRC the user that moves the object should have "delete" permission in the current OU.

Comment: I checked the above and the user still doesn't have the ability to move machines back. Really strange.

Comment: Check the effective rights of your group for that computer account